# How show category title on django

Tags: python, django

My problem is that in the category pages, title, meta title and meta description are not displayed.

I have shown it in the image I uploaded below.

How i can fix it?

Thank you

modles.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='children', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=70, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=70, unique=True)
    description = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, null=True)
    meta_title = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    meta_description = models.TextField(max_length=175, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.title
    
    class MPTTMeta:
       order_insertion_by = ['title']
```

views.py

```
class PostCategoryView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'posts_category.html'
    paginate_by = 9

    def get_queryset(self):
        slug = self.kwargs.get('slug')
        return Post.objects.filter(category__slug=slug, status=1)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data()
        context['category'] = Category.objects.all()
        return context
```

category template

```
{% extends 'shared/_MainLayout.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block head %}
{% block title %}**{{ category.meta_title }}**{% endblock %}
{% block description %}**{{ category.meta_description }}**{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
                <div class="page-header page-header-style-1 text-center mt-50">
                    <div class="container">
                        <h2><span class="color2">**{{ category.title }}**</span></h2>
                        <div class="breadcrumb">
                            <a href="/" rel="nofollow">Home</a> &nbsp; > &nbsp;
                            <span></span><a href="/{{ category.slug }}/" rel="nofollow">**{{ category.title }}**</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
{% endblock %}
```

[image: image of problem]

Comment: `category` is a queryset, not an instance of `Category` Model so you need to iterate it in order to get the result of each object.

Comment: I do not understand, if possible please show on the codes

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `context_object_name` to acces the object in the template. Or you can use the default name {{ object_list }}.

For example:

```
class PostCategoryView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'posts_category.html'
    paginate_by = 9
    context_object_name = Example
    model = Category

    def get_queryset(self):
        slug = self.kwargs.get('slug')
        return Post.objects.filter(category__slug=slug, status=1)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data()
        context['category'] = Category.objects.all()
        return context
```

Now you can use this in your template:

```
{% for category in Example %}
    <li>{{ category.title }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

If you do not set the context_object_name you can use the default name 'object_list' like this:

```
{% for category in object_list %}
    <li>{{ category.title }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

You also have to set your model in the ListView like: `model = Category`

Comment: When i set context_object_name when i set context_object_name an error occurs, but it work with object_list and {{ category.category.title }}.  Thanks alot

Comment: great! If you need some help with that error let me know and post your error here.

Comment: Thank you, but category title is repeated, for example we have 4 post in this category, 4 times category title repeated on header :(